# How to kill Merasmus, and where are the typical prop spawn points?

Tags: team-fortress-2

If you don't know what you're doing, Merasmus is a tough nut to crack. He's got plenty of HP, wide range attacks, he hides as a prop at half and ~10% health and a short timeout. Where does he hide? What's the best way to deal damage to him while he's vulnerable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, the single best way to take Merasmus down is as a **huntsman sniper.** While the relatively measly 16 arrows will have you hunting for ammo quite quickly (nothing a dispenser can't fix, mind you), you can charge your headshots quickly and deal more than a thousand damage every two seconds from any safe range. You won't additionally be causing explosive splash damage on "enemy teammates" who don't know better and are too close to Merasmus.

As for prop hunting, here is a possibly inexaustive list of places to check: (overhead image taken from [tf2portal.de](http://www.tfportal.de/?site=article_details&id=96))

[image]

Comment: Props can also be found around the control point up the stairs.
Also should point out that there are 5 props that spawn and that you must kill all of them to reveal Merasmus.
The ones I've seen are:
Rock, Pumpkin, Chair, Stone Slab, Health Cabinet, Red container
Otherwise great answer, +1!

Comment: @hammythepig No, you don't need to destroy all props. You just need to pick the right one; apparently, it's the one that bleeds green when hit!

Comment: Whenever I've shot any of the props, they all bleed green though.  It takes usually two shots of rocket/scatter gun/huntsman to break them, and when you break the first 4 a crit-giving-pumpkin comes out, and killing the last one releases Merasmus.  However all this is only from my experience, maybe on the servers i've been on we just happen to find him in the last one each time?  But I know each one bleeds green when you hit it.

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours of watching Mesmarus fly away at 3% hp I figured I'd put together a short guide on a a very effective strategy to kill Mesmarus every time he spawns.